# not able to redirect to page due to browser cache

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, redirect

I am developing simple app in cakephp. I have written a route for '/' to redirect to home page
I am using Auth component so when the url hits,Auth redirects the page to login page. when User logs in with proper credentials he will redirect to home page.

But browser cache the login page for '/' url, so even if user have correct credentials.It redirects to login page again. 
   Can I clear the browser cache somehow (not manually obviously)to avoid this?
thanks in adv

here is code :routes.php

```
Router::connect('/',array('controller' => 'employee', 'action' => 'index'));
```

In app Controller I have:

```
'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect'  => array(
            'plugin'     => false,
            'controller' => 'employee',
            'action'     => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'plugin'     => false,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action'     => 'login'
        ),
    )
```

in login action I have :

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, You have successfully logged in'), 'set_flash', array('class' => 'alert-success'));

                $this->redirect(array(
                                     'plugin'     => false,
                                     'controller' => 'employee',
                                     'action'     => 'index'
                                ));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'),
                    'set_flash',
                    array('class' => 'alert alert-error'));
            }
        }
```

It works properly if I clear the browser cache

Comment: Posting the code here what you have tried is definitely not an offence.

Comment: Does the `$_SESSION` appear to have successful login credentials upon hitting the login page second time?

Comment: sounds like a problem with your session .. not your cache

Comment: try to add a line "debug('here');" after the "Auth->login" condition, and the "exit()"; also on the "else", tosee if the login is really beig evaluated

Comment: @MackieeE yes I am getting credentials when I debug it. even $this->Auth->loggIn() returns true

Comment: `/` should be redirected to `/users/login` by AuthComponent. If that is the case, it's unlikely to be a browser cache issue, as the browser hasn't fetched any content for `/` yet (it was only redirected).

Comment: But use `print_r( $_SESSION )` to actually see =)

Comment: @priyanka What version of CakePHP are you using? It sounds pretty similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385756/cakephp-login-does-nothing) where versions are mixed up.

Comment: @Oldskool Yes,I checked that question and it looks similar but I am using 2.4 version of cakephp and As I mentioned It works fine when I clear browser cache